# My boss hired someone, knowing she had previously been rude to me. What options do I have?

Tags: management, colleagues

My boss and supervisor have been doing interviews for a position in the office I work in. One of the candidates interviewed was an employee who worked in a different department who had previously been rude to me. After expressing my concerns about that person to management they decided to hire her anyway. In addition, the way I found out was through accident they had no intentions of telling me at all. My request for transfer has been ignored and I'm not sure what options I have if any. Advice is needed and greatly appreciated.

Comment: How rude?  If she was still by far the best candidate, and the rudeness didn't extend to something actionable, what did you want them to do?  (Not that it matters - the only thing that matters is what you will do.)

Comment: @thursdaysgeek Rudeness can also interfere with teams that used to work together well, and result in everybody getting less done.  It can lead to drops in employee morale and increased turnover.

Comment: As far as "had previously been rude to me", do you mean on one or a few occasions, or every time you had to interact with that person?  Do you have reason to expect the rudeness to continue?  And how rude are we talking here?

Comment: You have the option to polish your CV and start searching for a new job

Comment: Honestly, this is more a question for interpersonal. Have you spoken to the employee that was rude to you about her actions? This is a matter between you and her, not your employer's business unless it causes problems. 
Your feelings of offendedness are your responsibility to deal with, and it was your choice to feel that way rather than to shrug it off, or forget it. 
You could go to her and say 'Look, before you came on board here, we had a bad interaction, and I felt slighted by it. I want us to be able to work together, but I feel the matter should be addressed professionally first."

Comment: "Has been rude to me" has such an enormous range of possibilities from almost harmless to being a punchable offence, it would be impossible to give any advice without some details.

Answer (score 13):

It sounds like your boss and supervisor considered her the best person for the job, in spite of your reservations.

Co-workers can be rude to other co-workers, and as long as it doesn't rise to the level of harassment based on protected classes, or some other actionable action in your region, you really have little recourse but to be polite and professional anyway.  (Well, you could be petty and rude in return, but if you want a good result, you need to be be professional.)

In other words, you can be polite and work with her, or you can find a different job.  Since you've already asked and been denied a transfer, a different job would be in a different company.

Answer (score 2):

Unless he or she have been past legal borders or behaves unprofessionally with most people, which he or she doesn't seem to, the problem is only a personal matter. The management should ignore this considering hiring.

Interfering with that process for a personal matter is fairly unethical, because it could prevent a qualified person to access a job. A more professional approach to raise the problem is to discuss the issue after the hiring so the management knows and can do something about it, like avoiding you two to work too closely.

However they don't even owe you that favor, and you will most likely have to deal with that person for some time - maybe trying to reposition, if really necessary - in which case it is probably best to try to start on a new page with that person. Maybe that person isn't too proud of the way he or she behaved with you and would be happy to establish a more professionnal relationship with you if given the chance.